# how to map dictionary to pandas series of series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to replace ditionary key value to  dataframe series of list value.

My Input:

dictionary:

```
   doc_id  name
     1      tamil.sh
     2      english.sh
     3      maths.sh
```

dataframe:

```
 doc_id     count 
  ["1","2"]     3
  ["2","3"]     4
```

I expect the Output of :

```
     doc_id               count
  ["tamil.sh","english.sh"]   3
  ["english.sh","maths.sh"]   4
```

Comment: why your `dict` looks like `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dictionary by first `DataFrame` by `zip` - here are keys integers, so if necessary in list comprehension and `get` is converting strings to `int`s for correct matchin values:

```
d = dict(zip(df1['doc_id'], df1['name']))
print (d)
{1: 'tamil.sh', 2: 'english.sh', 3: 'maths.sh'}

#values are strings, so converting to integers is necessary
print (df2.loc[0, 'doc_id'])
['1', '2']

df2['doc_id'] = df2['doc_id'].apply(lambda x: [d.get(int(y),y) for y in x])
print (df2)
                   doc_id  count
0  [tamil.sh, english.sh]      3
1  [english.sh, maths.sh]      4
```